# MySQL FROM Subquery with parent group by

Tags: mysql, sum, subquery, correlated-subquery

I need to show a ranking lists for a sport we manage.

It needs to sum up the 4 best results for each player (from a table that could have hundreds of results per player) and then sort the entire list from the player with the most points to least points.

The query below returns

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'r1.user_id' in 'where clause'

so I've gone off track somewhere.

```
SELECT r1.user_id, (
    SELECT SUM(points)
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM ranking_matrix_points r2
        WHERE user_id=r1.user_id
        ORDER BY points DESC
        LIMIT 4
    ) r3
) AS total_points
FROM ranking_matrix_points r1
WHERE
    user.status IN('active')
GROUP BY r1.user_id
ORDER BY total_points DESC
```

Comment: The issue is that MySQL only allows one level deep scope resolution in correlated subqueries as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution might be to number the rows for each user in order of points descending and then sum up the points with a rank <= 4. This might not perform very well though, and also you'll get a problem with ties (but you would have using limit too).

```
select user_id, sum(points) total_points
from (
  select user_id, points,
  ( 
    case user_id 
    when @cur_user 
    then @row := @row + 1 
    else @row := 1 and @cur_user := user_id end
  ) as rank
  from ranking_matrix_points,
  (select @row := 0, @cur_user := '') r
  order by user_id, points desc
) t
where rank <= 4
group by user_id;
```

I'm pretty sure there are better ways to do this but I can't think of any at the moment. This would have been very easy in just about any database with support for window functions, but sadly MySQL doesn't support any yet.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need a double query, just

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(points)
FROM ranking_matrix_points
WHERE user.status in('active')
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY total_points DESC
LIMIT 4
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 4 user_id, SUM(points)
FROM ranking_matrix_points
WHERE user.status in('active')
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY total_points DESC
```

Comment: This would change the entire meaning of the query and not get the desired result which is to get the sum of the top 4 scores _per user_ , Also MySQL does not use `top`

Comment: I don't see any user 2...this query only ask for an user and its points. Either that or something is bad written

Comment: Both of these SQL queries are wrong. MySQL also doesn't support TOP.

Comment: Ok, just re-readed your explanation, bad reader...let me check it back

Comment: @zon7 The 1 and 2 were list items; I guess it wasn't apparent due to the comment formatting.